# Why is my buffer being projected so large?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have a single point that I would like to make a buffer around. The point CRS is NAD83 EPSG:4269 `+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs`.

When I created a `Fixed distance buffer`, at just 10 meters, the buffer is huge. And I know it is incorrect because it is larger than the size of Texas and Texas is not 10 meters wide I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Sounds like your buffer distance is actually 10 degrees, not 10 meters.

Comment: @DanC I was thinking the same thing, but I was under the impression that the CRS I am using is in meters, so shouldn't it create the buffer in meters? And is there any way to change this?

Comment: Texas is about 10 degrees N/S, so I'd bet @DanC is right. Your projection also says proj=longlat. Reproject to something that uses meters and then try remaking your buffer.

Comment: Just as an experiment, given that 1 second of width or height is approximately 100 feet, try entering 0.00009258 as your buffer width.
This is the decimal equivalent of 1/3 of a second.
I do agree with @DanC & lambertj that your layer is in geographic coordinates, and should be reprojected into a NAD83 metric system, then create the buffer.

Comment: Units in EPSG:4269 are degrees http://epsg.io/4269.

Comment: @DanC Your comments would make a nice answer;)